# "Must include..." error deploying an existing Digital Experience into a Spring '23 scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, lightning-community, digital-experience

The error I'm seeing today deploying `experiences` metadata into a Spring '23 scratch org is:

> Object pages for the abc__Def__c object must include a details,
> a list, and a related list page.
>
> To deploy
> XYZ1/routes/defDetail.json, either include the other
> associated route files or delete all files related to
> abc__Def__c.
>
> Remember to update the corresponding files in the
> views folder also.

Anyone have any insight into this? The Digital Experience is made up of all custom LWCs and views. Was OK a couple of weeks ago.

Same error occurs for 54.0 or 57.0 (the latter requiring a `"isLockerServiceEnabled": true` property to be added).

Couple of details... there are routes containing:

```
  "objectApiName" : "abc__Def__c",
  "routeType" : "detail-a07",
```

```
  "objectApiName" : "abc__Def__c",
  "routeType" : "list-a07",
```

and corresponding views:

```
  "type" : "view",
  "viewType" : "detail-a07"
```

```
  "type" : "view",
  "viewType" : "list-a07"
```

Comment: Which template is the experience based on? And did you create object pages for `abc__Def__c` at all in your experience?

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Its a "Build Your Own (Aura)" template created about 18 months ago. I'll add a bit more to the question about the pages.

Comment: So you are missing the related list route and view? I guess Salesforce made a breaking change and now require all three. Or did `abc__Def__c` get updated so it now has related lists?

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Yes probably a breaking change and I'm looking for a work-around. I'll double check the template. Those `viewType` values seem more like arbitrary keys than than explicit types and the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) just says they should match. I don't see anything obvious in the views that designates details/list/related list either.

Comment: Looking in my views, I see a "viewType" that is "detail", "list" or "relatedlist". For the routes this is covered in the "routeType" similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent the morning trying to figure this out and eventually have got it working.

The `abc__Def__c` from the question is "Investment" in theses builder page lists:

[image: broken]      [image: fixed]

The left is taken from a pre-Spring '23 org and the right (after the fix) is taken from a Spring '23 org. Seems like the incomplete triplet of detail/list/related was not blocking deployment pre-Spring '23 but is now. The fix (for my case) was to convert the pages to not be `objectApiName` specific as their content does not require that, and the metadata will now deploy.

The [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) documentation, not too surprisingly, is more focussed on the data elements than higher level concepts such as "what is the difference between an Standard Page and an Object Page", a choice made in the builder when a new page is created as below. It does look like there is significant syntax in the `viewType` values; I had to change "detail-a07" to "custom-detail-a07" to get the deployment to work.

[image: page types]